# WMI and Win32_Process - determine if 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wmi

I wonder if there is any value I can check on win32_process to see if it is a x86 or x64 process?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: i think [this](http://forums.soccerfansnetwork.com/showthread.php?26534-Additional-data-that-describes-the-application-s-condition-is-required.) can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use just WMI to find out is process 32 or 64 bit, but you can use process ID that you obtain wia WMI or process enumeration and then call windows api IsWow64Process, here is a help :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There is a ton of info how to use that API from managed code, just google it :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was hoping that I wouldn't have to go the extra roundtrip for retrieving the process as well.